# Cannot unmount /cdrom, but my laptop doesn´t have it!

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 64-bit to my new USB. I formatted partition to EXT4, but when i start installation, it throws this: Cannot unmount /cdrom. BUT, my laptop doesnt have cd rom! Why is /dev/sda1 mounted on /cdrom? Please help! (im new, so dont be rude. please.)

Comment: Are you trying to install to the same USB you're booting the live session / installer from?

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, i am. is that causing the problem? Sorry, but im new to linux.

Comment: So don't, because you can't. You need one to run the live session from, and another drive, internal or external, where to install to. It's that simple.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you! But... why is the USB mounted on /cdrom? my laptop doesnt have it.. but thank you so much!

Comment: Because the live/installation media is made out of an (optical) drive ISO9660 image file so it *emulates* said drive.

Comment: Oh... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have two USBs. One for Live session and one for installation.

Comment: ChanganAuto was saying that an ISO used for installation is an optical drive ISO9660 image file, and is intended to emulate a cdrom. You do not need two USBs. The Live Session automatically mounts on /cdrom as it is emulating the mounting of a disk image.

Comment: @Jeff. He needs 2 USB-devices to install Ubuntu to a USB-device. So the minus 1 you gave the answer is not correct.

Comment: @JoepieEs It is a logical downvote. You do *not* need a separate USB to run a live session. Installation medium and the live session use the same USB disk. You must have another USB to install Ubuntu on though. That is not what slavekrouta was saying. He was under the impression that he needed two separate USBs to run a live session and install Ubuntu onto another disk.

Comment: @Jeff In the first line he says 'I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 64-bit to my new USB'. So he wants to install ( with the USB medium ) to a USB medium. See also comments from Changanauto and the respons. So he needs 2. You are right about the live version and the installation files are on 1 USB medium.

Comment: @JoepieEs My bad, I didn't see that. Disregard my comments.